# mock-server and OpenSSL: Unable to load the library 'netty_tcnative_windows_x86_64'

Tags: java, ssl, netty, mockserver

To test a clients HTTP(S) communication I am using "[mock-server](http://mock-server.com/)". Currently I want to test a TLS connect but get the following error:

```
i.n.u.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.workdir: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp (io.netty.tmpdir)
i.n.u.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'netty_tcnative_windows_x86_64', trying other loading mechanism.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative_windows_x86_64 in java.library.path
```

My gradle dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'org.mock-server:mockserver:5.3.0'
testImplementation 'org.mock-server:mockserver-netty:5.3.0'
testImplementation 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:2.0.7.Final:windows-x86_64' 
testImplementation 'io.netty:netty-tcnative:2.0.7.Final:windows-x86_64'
```

In the temp-folder I can see the dll's in question, e.g:

- *netty_tcnative_windows_x86_646745663469304581179.dll*
- *netty_tcnative7389825183963439904.dll*

Is this a dependency issue? Do I need to download other versions of netty?

Comment: Looks like you've missed a platform specific netty jar in your java class path. Check your pom.xml/build.xml etc and IDE run-script.

Comment: @VictorGubin the dll's are in the temp-folder, seems like netty don't find them